# Expand alias in ZSH history

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, command-history

I have the following alias in my zshrc

```
alias nif='nvim $(rg --files | fzf -m || echo +qa)'
```

Essentially, I use rg (ripgrep) to show all the files in the current directory and in sub directories. This is piped into fzf where I can select some of them and it is then opened in neovim. When all is said and done the final command ends up being something like

```
nvim my_file.cpp
```

However in my history it just shows the `nif` alias. Is there any way to replace `nif` in my history with the command it expanded into like `nvim my_file.cpp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your alias add itself its expansion to the history with `print -s`.

Instead of:

```
alias nif='nvim $(...)'
```

use

```
alias nif='f=$(...); print -rs nvim $f; nvim $f'
```

Same thing works with a function instead of an alias, which means that you can abstract & reuse the history-saving instead of duplicating it in all your aliases.

Comment: That works to add the expansion into the history, but it leaves `nif` in the history too. Is there any way to replace the alias rather than just adding its expansion?

Comment: A command line is added to the history before the aliases are expanded. You can prevent it being added to the history with eg. `zshaddhistory(){ [[ $1 != nif\ * ]] }`. Though I don't see the point of that.

Comment: Any way to edit an entry in the history file? Instead of preventing it from being added in the first place, it would also work to just override it.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that.

Comment: You can prevent the alias from getting into history by setting: `HISTORY_IGNORE="(nif)"`

Comment: That will only prevent it from being written to the history file;  it will still be added to the in-memory / per-session history.

Comment: Hm, this only works for a particular alias. But hey, you taught me that I can change where the parameters are applied in an alias, I always thought I have to use a function for that!
Anyways, I'd like to expand _all_ aliases in history...